# Prompt for values until press ENTER key with empty value

Tags: linux, bash, centos, script

I'm working in a bash script for automatize some tasks. This is what I have done until now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("Create new group" "Add users to group" "Change directory ownership" "Change directory permissions" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Create new group")
            read -e -p "Enter the group name: " -i "www-pub" groupname
            groupadd groupname
            echo "You have added a new group: " groupname
            ;;
        "Add users to group")
            ## Here 
            ;;
        "Change directory ownership")
            read -e -p "Enter the group name: " -i "www-pub" "Enter the directory: " -i "/var/www/html" groupname directory
            chown -R root:groupname directory
            echo "You have changed the ownership for: " directory " to root:" groupname
            ;;
        "Change directory permissions")
            ## Actions for change directory permissions goes here
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done
```

Now in step 2 `Add users to group` I want to add more than one user to a given group. So:

- Can I use previous `groupname` asked on step1 or should I ask for a `groupname` always?
- I need to ask for more than one user for add it to the group by running this command: `usermod -a -G groupname username`, how do I ask for them until empty value?

As example:

```
Add users to group
Enter the group name: www-pub
Enter user: user1
user1 added to www-pub
Enter user: user2
user2 added to www-pub
Enter user: (none hit ENTER without values)
Return to the main menu
```

Can any give me some help to build this block of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
    "Add users to group")
        read -e -p "Enter the group name: " -i "www-pub" groupname
        loop=true          # "true" is a command
        while $loop; do    # the "$loop" command is executed
            read -p "enter username: " username
            if [[ -z $username ]]; then
                loop=false # this command returns a fail status, and
                           # will break the while loop
            else
                # add user to group
            fi
        done
        ;;
```

A more concise way:

```
        while true; do
            read -p "enter username: " username
            [[ -z $username ]] && break
            # add user
        done
```